# Protecting json generating script/handlers for ajax requests

Tags: php, ajax, json, curl

I generate json message in json.php on `my site . com`. I am making cURL request in php script and sending session id as cookie. So script see that user (which request this script) is authorised and script prints json for him.

php script:

```
$ch = curl_init($json_url);
$ses_id = session_id(); 
$cookie = 'PHPSESSID='.$ses_id.';';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

#working with json data
```

json.php:

```
if($_SESSION['UserAuthorized']) {
    #print json there
}
```

Is this enought? I am thinking no and trying to add some defence to this page. I thought about checking IP or referrer. IP:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
var_dump($ip);
```

On local server all working fine, but on hosting it shows not 127.0.0.1 (not localhost, but some ip). I use virtual hosting, thats why I have problems there.

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFFERER']` shows nothing anyway (opening with browser or sending http request with cURL):

```
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFFERER'];
var_dump($ref);
```

output is NULL.

About ajax requests. I can use next:

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
#add/delete/edit db for ex etc
}
```

But... is this enought?

So the questions:

1. Is methods which I use is enought for protecting json/ajax handlers
   scripts?
2. Any suggestions/explaining why http_referrer not works?

Answer (score 0):

1. You could verify that `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to check if the request is from the same server. Don't trust `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` as it could be easily modified.
2. Referrer is only set if you have one. If you are calling the page directly (curl or typing the url in the browser) or if you have the referrer-header disabled in your browser it won't be sent to the server.

Besides that, you should really think through the design. Why can't you access the data directly from the first PHP-script (now containing the curl)? How is json.php generating it's output, can you replace/include that logic to your first PHP-script?

Comment: can you replace/include that logic to your first PHP-script? — its a good question. I can access data directly, but code would be awfull in that case (tonns of sql-requests, outputs etc in one place). Now I have loading data in one place, output data in another place (not mvc :) but it is much better to upgrade code now, more readable now. Also , I will use this data in js (may be yes, may be not)

Comment: It's indeed a good practice to seperate your model (loading of the data) and your view (displaying it). But a curl-request realy isn't the best solution. Use classes/functions to fetch your data from the database, use a simple `include('model.php')` and a function-call to retrieve your data (instead of curl). If you want to access your data via javascript (json) at a later stadium, add a json.php with the same `include('model.php')`.

Comment: hm. maybe its a good idea. i will think about it. thought json will be better there. ty.

Comment: It seems like a good idea (in terms of seperating data and view), but then you're 1. retrieve data from db to PHP, 2. converting PHP-data into JSON, 3. sending JSON over an curl-request, 4. converting JSON-string back into PHP. A lot of overhead where only step 1 is really necessary.

Comment: Ok. Now I am making form submit handler. I send form as ajax request. How I can handle this request without creating new file, which will return only some messages, which I will output somewhere near 'send' button? All requests are going throw index.php, that's why using it will return full html structure (which is situated in index.php). But in ajax response I need only message like 'okay, data added' or error message, not full page code. Do you understand me?

Comment: Why don't you want to create a new file? For example do something like: 1. index.php: execute request (read POST-data, store in db etc), and include either 2 or 3. (depending of request type) -- 2. view.html.php: show result as HTML -- 3. view.json.php: show result as AJAX. Seperating those in multiple files makes your code easy to read.

Comment: Can you give an example?